# Nested directories, import and includegraphics

Tags: import

I am currently experiencing a problem using quite nested directories.
So I have the following folder and file structure:

```
/root
   /images
   /other_folder
```

The root folder contains my `header.tex` and a main file. They would look sth like this:

```
%header.tex
\documentclass...
\usepackages...
\includegraphics{images/image}

%main.tex
\input{header.tex}
\begin{document}
.
.
\end{document}
```

the header file contains also the design and layout for the pages, thus the `\includegraphics` command found in there.

Now I have the problem that I want to create a new document with the design found in `/root/header.tex`, but I want to create the document in `/root/other_folder/new_doc.tex`

I have tried the following in the `/root/other_folder/new_doc.tex`:

```
\input{../header.tex} %inputs the header file, but doesn't find the images
\subimport{../}{header} %behaves as above.
```

Note that the whole preamble is found in the `/root/header.tex`. For the `\subimport`, I had to move the `\documentclass` command to the `new_doc` file and remove it from header, but the problem is the same as with input: the `\includegraphics` command is run from the subdirectory `other_folder/` instead of from the root.

Is there any way to add the `header.tex` into this file, with keeping the `\includegraphics` commands intact for the main document? I would like to keep the design in one single file, so each time I want to make changes, I can automatically apply them to all documents using the design.

My last resort would be to create a `make.sh`, which just copies the necessary files each time before running `pdflatex`, but I hope that the community finds a more elegant solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could set `\graphicspath{..}`.

Comment: Okay, so of course 5 minutes after posting the question I came up with a first version of the answer: I just took the \documentclass and \usepackage{graphicx} commands out of the header (because they won't really ever change} and added the \graphicspath to the preambel. Now I can change this path for the documents, depending on their position within the directories and after cropping the image path out of the \includegraphics, this should work now.

edit: TeXnician was quicker. Thanks for your answer

Comment: your question is very unclear you say `\includegraphics` is in your header file which is input in to the preamble, but that would generate an error, you can not typeset in the preamble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using the \includegraphics within a \DeclareNewLayer environment which is then called through a \AddLayersToPageStyle. I don't know why it works, but it does. Maybe it is only called inside the document itself?

Comment: so your code snippet in the question is not only impossible for anyone to use, it is totally misleading as it shows `\includegraphics` at the same level as `\usepackage` which would generate an error. No one will be able to help you if you do not show what you are doing, nor say what error you get.